# Look Up Table with Unequally Spaced Ranges

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, lookup

Im trying to implement a look up table for a set of unequal ranges. The idea is, when given an input, the code should look up the "value" corresponding to the range it lies in.

Here is an example (please check the link- cannot post images yet)

[Example Look Up table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPM2T.jpg)

So if I gave an input of 12, the output should be 2.
example code

I've written an if/else type code which checks if any given input lies in a particular given interval and then proceeds to output the value of the interval it is located in. Now, I want to avoid the whole "if else" style solution and make this more efficient and make sure the more efficient process can take in a numpy array. Could anyone please help out with this?  Thank you

Comment: Are all the input values of data type int?

Comment: In the example the ranges overlap, I suppose this is just a typo, but the other important thing is if are there any gaps in between ranges? if not, then you can just create a list with the upper values of the ranges and that would make the code much cleaner

Comment: @jayvee, There is no overlap in the example. The upper boundaries are inclusive and the lower boundaries are exclusive.

Comment: Input data types are not of the type int and you can assume my actual range intervals are not the "neat" integers I provided as an example earlier.